# How do I frame walls on an uneven concrete slab?

Tags: walls, garage

I'd like to convert (and finish) the back section of my 2-car tandem garage into a separate utility room.  This would involve 4 walls and a floor.  2 of the walls would be attached to concrete walls, 1 would be attached to existing house/garage wall, one would be new to separate front car space from rear utility space. My concrete slab garage floor is sloped towards the center to allow for drainage into a sewer pipe.

How do I frame everything to be plumb and level when the garage floor has slope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Fasten your bottom plates to the floor where you want your walls.
2. Use a long level or a laser to mark straight up from the bottom plates to the ceiling.
3. Fasten your top plates to the ceiling.
4. Measure all the studs individually and toe nail them into the plates.

Comment: The slope of the concrete garage floor is away from the face of the wall.   If I fasten a sole plate to the floor and then mark straight from the face of the plate, the stud will be at an angle protruding further away from the wall at the top.  Hope this makes sense, I'll try to get a picture.     Options might be to shim the sole plate to be level (flat), or cut the studs at some mitered angle so that they extend plumb from the sole plate.  Not sure what is best option here (or some other choice).

Comment: I know what your saying. We usually don't bother cutting on an angle but it's up to you. I'd do that instead of shimming the plates.

Answer (score 1):

You could lay your top and bottom plate, then measure and cut each stud. But since it's not structural you can prefab your wall a little short of your finished dimensions and then shim under each stud. Either way a chalk line and a laser really help